# XNA - Render to a texture's alpha channel

Tags: xna, rendering, textures, render-to-texture

I have a texture that I want to modify it's alpha channel in runtime.
Is there a way to draw on a texture's alpha channel ?
Or maybe replace the channel with that of another texture ?

Thanks,
SW.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What data are you trying to put into the alpha channel? There are many ways to do this and most of them have performance implications.

Comment: I'm trying to make a complex transition between two images. I have a solver that generates fluid effect, and I want that fluid as the alpha channel of a texture. So yes, performance is an issue, as I need to update this channel every frame, and the texture is large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, based on your comment, what you should do is use a pixel shader. Your source image doesn't even need an alpha channel - let the pixel shader apply an alpha.

In fact you should probably calculate the values for the alpha channel (ie: run your fluid solver) on the GPU as well.

Your shader might look something like this:

```
float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    float4 c = tex2D(textureSampler, uv);
    c.A = /* calculate alpha value here */;
    return c;
}
```

A good place to start would be the XNA [Sprite Effects](https://web.archive.org/web/20141116072421/http://create.msdn.com:80/en-US/education/catalog/sample/sprite_effects) sample.

There's even an effect similar to what you are doing:
[image]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://create.msdn.com/assets/cms/images/XNA_SpriteEffects_02_small.jpg))</sub>

The effect in the sample reads from a second texture to get values for the calculation of the alpha channel of the first texture when it is drawn.